Cannot Read Properties of Undefined in Gnosis Safe SDK with Ethers.js
I am working on a script to withdraw USDT from a Gnosis Safe (now known as Safe) on the Binance Smart Chain using the latest Safe SDK and Ethers.js.
This script is designed to withdraw USDT from a Gnosis Safe (now known as Safe) on the Binance Smart Chain using the Safe SDK and Ethers.js. The script initializes two wallets, creates a transaction to transfer USDT from the Safe to a recipient address, and requires signatures from both wallets to execute the transaction.
I encountered a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getNetwork') when initializing the EthersAdapter.
Here are the steps I followed and the code I used:
Project Initialization:
Removed existing node_modules and package-lock.json.
Reinitialized the project with npm init -y.
Installed dependencies using
npm install ethers@5.7.0 @safe-global/protocol-kit @safe-global/safe-ethers-lib

Issue
Error during execution: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getNetwork')
    at EthersAdapter.getChainId (path/to/@safe-global/safe-ethers-lib/dist/src/EthersAdapter.js:62:81)
    ...

Script
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const Safe = require('@safe-global/protocol-kit').default;
const EthersAdapter = require('@safe-global/safe-ethers-lib').default;

// Define your constants (replace placeholders with actual values)
const PRIVATE_KEY1 = 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY1';
const PRIVATE_KEY2 = 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY2';
const SAFE_ADDRESS = 'YOUR_SAFE_ADDRESS';
const TOKEN_ADDRESS = 'YOUR_TOKEN_ADDRESS';
const RECIPIENT_ADDRESS = 'YOUR_RECIPIENT_ADDRESS';
const PROVIDER_URL = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/';

async function main() {
    console.log('Connecting to the Binance Smart Chain...');
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(PROVIDER_URL);

    // Initialize wallets
    const wallet1 = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY1, provider);
    const wallet2 = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY2, provider);
    console.log(`Wallet1 address: ${wallet1.address}`);
    console.log(`Wallet2 address: ${wallet2.address}`);

    // Initialize EthersAdapter for both wallets
    const ethAdapter1 = new EthersAdapter({
        ethers,
        signer: wallet1
    });

    const ethAdapter2 = new EthersAdapter({
        ethers,
        signer: wallet2
    });

    // Load the Safe with the first wallet
    const safeSdk1 = await Safe.create({
        ethAdapter: ethAdapter1,
        safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS
    });

    // Check the balance of the Safe
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(TOKEN_ADDRESS, [
        "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
        "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) returns (bool)"
    ], provider);

    const balance = await tokenContract.balanceOf(SAFE_ADDRESS);
    const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits('10.0', 18); // Assuming USDT has 18 decimals
    console.log(`Balance in Safe: ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance, 18)} USDT`);

    if (balance.lt(amount)) {
        console.error('Not enough tokens in the Safe to perform the transaction');
        return;
    }

    // Prepare the transaction
    const data = tokenContract.interface.encodeFunctionData("transfer", [RECIPIENT_ADDRESS, amount]);
    const safeTransactionData = {
        to: TOKEN_ADDRESS,
        value: '0',
        data: data
    };

    // Create the transaction
    const safeTransaction = await safeSdk1.createTransaction([safeTransactionData]);
    await safeSdk1.signTransaction(safeTransaction);

    // Load Safe with the second wallet and sign the transaction
    const safeSdk2 = await Safe.create({
        ethAdapter: ethAdapter2,
        safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS
    });

    await safeSdk2.signTransaction(safeTransaction);
    console.log('Transaction has been signed by both wallets, ready to execute...');

    // Execute the transaction
    try {
        const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk1.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);
        const receipt = await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse.wait();
        console.log(`Transaction successful with hash: ${receipt.transactionHash}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during transaction execution:', error);
    }
}

main().catch(err => {
    console.error('Error during execution:', err);
});

Could someone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it?

On the latest versions of the SDK (which you are probably using), we have removed the need for adapters. Please refer to the new protocol kit reference to learn how to initialize your Safe the correct way.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
